# Turning 1 Column Containing Sets of Data into Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, one-to-many, vba

I have a CSV formatted as such:

```
label1,data1
label2,data2
label3,data3

label1,data4
label2,data5
label3,data6

... etc ...
```

I'm try to transform it in Excel to this format:

```
label1,label2,label3
data1,data2,data3
data4,data5,data6
```

I don't think this is possible with the built-in tool so I'm looking at writing a macro for it, but I'm a PowerShell/C# person and not a VB person.  Any assistance or guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make the assumption that this is a one time thing and a spreasheet formula will suit you.

You can use this custom spreadsheet function from **mikerickson** on OzGrid to concatenate all data with a common label.

First you need to get all your unique values:

[image: Example1]

Then you need to use this custom function to lookup and concatenate values with a common label:

```
Function ConcatIf(ByVal compareRange As Range, ByVal xCriteria As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal stringsRange As Range, Optional Delimiter As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, criteriaMet As Boolean

    Set compareRange = Application.Intersect(compareRange, _
    compareRange.Parent.UsedRange)

    If compareRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If stringsRange Is Nothing Then Set stringsRange = compareRange
    Set stringsRange = compareRange.Offset(stringsRange.Row - compareRange.Row, _
    stringsRange.Column - compareRange.Column)

    For i = 1 To compareRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To compareRange.Columns.Count
            If (Application.CountIf(compareRange.Cells(i, j), xCriteria) = 1) Then
                ConcatIf = ConcatIf & Delimiter & CStr(stringsRange.Cells(i, j))
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ConcatIf = Mid(ConcatIf, Len(Delimiter) + 1)
End Function
```

[image: Example2]

You can do an additional concatenation to combine your label if you want:

[image: Example3]

Then you can paste that directly into a text editor or you can use it as is, save it as a csv if you want:

[image: Example4]

Then you open that in excel and transpose it if you want:

[image: Example5]

Kind of a round-a-bout way to do it, but it's going to be easier than writing a macro in my opinion - slightly at least. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate technique may depend somewhat on how often you need to do this and how many blocks of data you have but a macro is not necessary:

Import into Excel and split Text to Columns with comma as separator.
Shunt down three rows and move one set of "label1 label2 label3" above the 'data' column.
Delete 'label' column and blank rows.
Copy column into Word as unformatted text.
Insert > Tables -Table, Convert Text to Table with Number of columns =3.
Copy back into Excel and concatenate by row with coma delimiters (`&","&`)